# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'List'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2010

myconn.Open()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from Food where Food List = @list", myconn)
        command.Parameters.Add("@list", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbox1.Text
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)

the error i get will show at the adapter.fill(table) saying i have non boolean type at(Food List) how do i fix this any idea?beginner at vb

Comment: Hey man, this is a little hard to understand what you are asking. Would you be able to clean it up a bit?

Comment: Show us SQL and **not** VB(?) code! Extract the SQL string and post that here - along with the table defintions (**AS DDL**, i.e. `CREATE TABLE foo (...);`). There are some articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: you have a space between food and list.. try put it between  [ ]